# How do I transfer data from my desktop through Command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, acer-aspire

My windows 10 tablet/laptop (Asper Aspire Switch) is corrupted and keeps doing a repair boot loop which I can not fix no matter what way I try. Firstly, I would like to get all my data which is stored on the desktop via the command prompt - can anyone please send me a link for a guide on how to do this? I know it can be done as a i had a friend do it for me but unfortunately it only copied 400mb of data not the 64gb of data i wanted. Does anyone know the commands to transfer the data on to a usb drive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if you can sign in in Safe Mode and use the Copy Command. If not, remove the drive, put it is a carrier and recover the data that way.

Comment: what do you mean by 'put it as a carrier'. with this device i cant even find the hard drive, i read that the data is stored on a chip.

Comment: You may need to take the computer to a local computer store to recover the data.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is *not* with the command prompt, running in the OS, but by *booting from USB or CD/DVD*. Once you do that, make a complete disk image, which saves *everything* on the disk, and does it *much faster* than copying separate files, without the risk of using a flaky, or perhaps malware-infected OS.

To do this, there are many excellent, free tools such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). In general, these imaging tools can make a bootable USB drive, which has it own operating system, such as Microsoft's *Win RE*, as in *Reflect*, or Linux. Yes, it means getting access to another PC and using a USB drive, but is a far better choice. The steps using *Reflect* are as follows:

- Download and install *Macrium Reflect* on another PC.
- Insert a USB drive with at least 8 GB capacity. **N.B.** It will be formatted, and all data erased from it, in the next operation.
- Open it, and on the menu, select *Other Tasks | Create Rescue Media*.
- Follow the prompts to *carefully* select the correct USB drive and make it a bootable drive with *Macrium Reflect* on it.
- Insert the USB device in the *powered off* Acer Aspire Switch.
- [Select the boot device](https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/12915-changing-boot-order) with <kbd>F12</kbd>, if enabled, or from BIOS/UEFI with <kbd>F2</kbd>, otherwise.
- Boot from the USB drive and save an image of the laptop's SSD to another USB drive (or even the same one, if you have over 64 GB left).

Comment: I have tried booting from usb but it comes back with an error saying cannot find bootable usb device please select other device to boot from etc..

Comment: You need to turn Secure Boot OFF in BIOS to start  with your USB Key.

Comment: I've done that as well. Turn it off, reset the default settings.

Comment: I thought it may be the USB stick being 2.0 instead of 3.0 so we bought a new one and still nothing. same error appears

Comment: There are differing instructions for booting from USB for each computer model. Consult your PC's manufacturer's manual for directions. As for Secure Boot, my experience with Reflect is that there were *no* changes needed to BIOS, though that might be different for another PC. More likely, the USB was not correctly made -- look carefully at the instructions for making it, let it download new WAIK files, *wait* for building installation *data* to complete, *wait* for all data to be put on the USB, and use the Windows *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* before yanking it out.

Comment: Maybe I didn't install it correctly I will try again. If I use a 64gb usb stick to install the reflect on, What will happen if I use the same usb for copying the image to? Will it overwrite the software? I don't have any higher usb, and my laptop only has one usb port! so silly..

Comment: Many PC's *at boot* cannot read USB formatted other than FAT32. Large devices might be exFAT. If it's exFAT, here's the issue -- reformat FAT32, or use a smaller drive. See https://macrorit.com/partition-magic-manager/create-fat32-volume-larger-than-32gb.html for formatting.